# Random image-background in div

Tags: javascript, css, html, random

I have a "container" DIV that scales to fit the window 100% and I would like to load a random image into the DIV.
I have a working script that works for the html background, but I can't get it to work on a DIV instead.

Anyn suggestions?

Here is the original script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var imgCount = 3;
    var dir = 'images/';
    var randomCount = Math.round(Math.random() * (imgCount - 1)) + 1;
    var images = new Array
            images[1] = "bg-01.jpg",
            images[2] = "bg-02.jpg",
            images[3] = "bg-03.jpg",
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + dir + images[randomCount] + ")"; </script>
```

Comment: And what is a problem with div? Show your code where you are trying to set a background for a div, not for body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should be no problem with that. Just find that div, for instance with document.getElementById() and apply a background image to it:

```
<div id="divID"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var imgCount = 3;
        var dir = 'images/';
        var randomCount = Math.round(Math.random() * (imgCount - 1)) + 1;
        var images = new Array
                images[1] = "bg-01.jpg",
                images[2] = "bg-02.jpg",
                images[3] = "bg-03.jpg",
        document.getElementById("divID").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + dir + images[randomCount] + ")"; 
   </script>
```

But note that above script block must go AFTER a div you need to update.
Otherwise, at the moment of script execution div will be not available in DOM and `document.getElementById` will find nothing.

Comment: Perfect! I had tried "getElementById" before, but I hadn't placed if AFTER the div.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

`document.body.style.backgroundImage` sets the background to `<body>`

You can easily force it to do it for your selected div by doing:

```
document.getElementById('divID').style.backgroundImage = "url(" + dir + images[randomCount] + ")";
```